Proof of Taylor's formula for polynomials
the formula I'm talking about is:
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and f a polynomial. Then $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(i)}(a)(x-a)^i}{i!}$.
In my textbook there is a proof for this theorem, but there is a reasoning I  don't fully understand.
"Assume we have a polynomial $f(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{0}$ with coefficients $a_n,...,a_0 \in \mathbb{R}.$ Say $x = (a+h)$. Then we get: $f(a+h) = a_n(a+h)^n+a_{n-1}(a+h)^{n-1}+...+a_{0}.$We can use Newton's Binomium to calculate the exponents and this results in the following: $f(a+h) = b_{n}h^n+b_{n-1}h^{n-1}+...+b_{0}$ for some $b_0,...,b_n \in \mathbb{R}.$
I think the following is happening: if we use Newton's binomium formula we get a sum of different terms for each exponentiation but we are only intersted in the powers of $h$ so we "put" all others terms in the coëfficients $b_0,b_1,...,b_n$. What do you think of this reasoning? Is it correct or should i be more precise?

It is correct.${}$
